# Can we have two different Microsoft Integration Runtime version for dev and prod datafactory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Planning to upgrade Dev data factory gateway from 5.14 version to 5.16.
Will this affect the ci cd process?
Prod datafactory is having 5.14.

Following the Microsoft given ci cd relase process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SHIR version will be fine but do your test.

Integration runtimes and sharing. Integration runtimes don't change often and are similar across all stages in your CI/CD. So Data Factory expects you to have the **same name and type of integration runtime across all stages of CI/CD**. If you want to share integration runtimes across all stages, consider using a ternary factory just to contain the shared integration runtimes. You can use this shared factory in all of your environments as a linked integration runtime type.

[Best practices for CI/CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#best-practices-for-cicd)

Comment: Same name and type (linked/shared) is fine. I asked only for impact of the IntegrationRuntime_msi version.

 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717

Comment: which ntegration runtime are you talking about. SH-IR or auto-IR?

Comment: the Self hosted integration runtime.

Comment: You should be fine but the recommendation is to have both at the same level and Update with the new SHIR version. 

In short, answer if will be fine in theory but please test it.